# React Navtive (React JS) props is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, undefined, react-props

I need some help.
If i write  `props.customFields.current`    <----- it works ✅
but if i write like ...  `const { customFields } = props`  <--- customField is undefined  (same in other props like onEdit, edit ...etc )

I don't understand why results are different.
Please you guys help me

This is my project structure.
Properties.js  PropertyGroups.js  PropertyItem.js  TypeRadio.js
customFields

[image: PropertyItem.js]

customFields are passed by props (atrribute)

[image: TypeRadio.js]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot Destructure prop values like that . Try Destructuring like this :

```
const Component = ({ customFields }) => {
  return (
      <div>{customFields}</div>
  )
}
```

You can use `const { fieldInsideCustomFields } = customFields`  only If the customFields prop itself has another field inside of it .

```
const customFields = {
   fieldInsideCustomFields : "string"
}

<Component customFields={customFields} />
```

Using the field `fieldInsideCustomFields` inside `customFields` prop :

```
const Component = ({ customFields }) => {
  const { fieldInsideCustomFields } = customFields
  return (
      <div>{fieldInsideCustomFields}</div>
  )
}
```